# Showing that a subspace of $L^p$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

I would like to prove that a particular subspace of $L^p([1,\infty[)$ (for some $p \in [1,\infty[$) is closed, but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

> For any sequence $(x_n) \in \ell^p$, let define 
>   $f_{(x_n)} : a \mapsto x_{\lfloor a \rfloor}$ (which is a "step" function, belonging to $L^p([1,\infty[)$).
>   Then, I want to show that the subspace $E = \{f_{x} \mid x \in l^p \}$ is closed in $L^p([1,\infty[)$.

My idea was to take a sequence $f_{\,\stackrel{\rightarrow}{x}_n}$ in $E$ (where $\stackrel{\rightarrow}x_n = (x_{m,n})_{m \geq 1}$ is an element of $l^p$, for all $n ≥1$) that converges (for the $L^p$-norm) to some $g \in L^p$. Then I want to show that $g \in E$.

I think that I could use the fact that some subsequence of $(f_{\,\stackrel{\rightarrow}{x}_n})_{n ≥ 1}$ converges almost everywhere to $g$. But I find that this would be complicated ; anyway I don't see how to continue.

This is why I'm asking for some help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to show the closeness we have to prove that if a sequence $(x_n)\in E \rightarrow x \in L^p \Rightarrow x \in E$.

Assume we have such sequence and $x \not\in E$, it means that $\exists z \in [1,\infty[$ such that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \; x((z-\varepsilon,z+\varepsilon))$ is not constant whenever we change a set of measure zero.

But by construction $(x_n)$ is constant $\forall n$ in the above interval (if we are on a edge just take the left or right side). So

$$\|x_n - x\|_{L^p(z-\varepsilon,z+\varepsilon)} \leq 
\text{ess}\!\!\!\sup_{(z-\varepsilon,z+\varepsilon)}|x_n-x|^p \times 2\varepsilon > \delta >0.$$

This is impossible since

$$\|x_n-x\|_{L^p}=\|x_n-x\|_{L^p(]1,\infty] \setminus (z \pm \varepsilon))} + \|x_n-x\|_{L^p(z \pm \varepsilon)} > \delta$$ and there is no convergence anymore.

Comment: Ok, thank you! By contradiction, there is some interval $[m,m+1[$ on which the function $x$ takes at least two distinct values $x(a)$ and $x(b)$ (on a non-zero measure set $A$ and $B$ respectively). Then (for $p=1$) :

$$\int_m^{m+1} |x_n-x| ≥ \int_A |x_n - x(a)| + \int_B |x_n - x(b)| 
≥\\≥ s \cdot (|x_n - x(a)|+|x_n - x(b)|) ≥ s \cdot |x(a)-x(b)| =: \delta > 0$$

where $s=\min(m(A),m(B))$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $f_n$ a sequence of $L^p$ that converge to $f$. Since $x\longmapsto |x|^p$ is convex when $p\geq 1$, $$|f|^p=2^p\left|\frac{f-f_n+f_n}{2}\right|^p\leq 2^{p-1}(|f_n-f|^p+|f_n|^p).$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't see how to continue: if  $f_n \in E$ for all $n≥1$, then why is $f \in E$? From your hint, I know that $$\|f\|_p ≤ 2^{(p-1)/p} \;\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \|f_n\|_p$$... and then?